# jQuery smooth scroll to anchor affecting Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website that has anchor links down every page which smooth scroll to the next section when clicked with the help of jQuery. Alongside this, I am using a Bootstrap 4 carousel as the top hero on most pages.

The carousel was working perfectly fine until I created the smooth scroll function; and now since the carousel uses anchor links to get the two navigational arrows works they no longer work as intended. (They scroll down the page to the top of the hero image instead of rotating the carousel images.)

My question, is how can I modify my small jQuery function (or something else entirely) to make my carousel ID exempt from this.

```js
// Smooth scroll when anchor link
$('a').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```html
  
  <div class="slide-controls-container">
    <div class="slide-controls">
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#hero-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="z-index:5;">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mq7hVd5/prev.png" alt="next" />
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#hero-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="z-index:5;">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/w04vMXH/next.png" alt="next" />
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried specifying not to include the carousel class like follows:

```
$('a:not(.hero-carousel a[href=#])').click
```

But this makes the entire smooth scroll not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to make it a lot harder than it had to be, I simply had to add a class to the anchor links that I wished to smooth scroll and then specify that class in my jQuery function.

```js
// Smooth scroll when anchor link
$('a.chevron-link').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="chevron">
  <a class="chevron-link" href="#next-section"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
</div>
```

Apologies, and thanks for the help